# How to add the "Home" button to a custom menu in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

I've made a custom menu in wordpress that contains some pages that I want, but there is no "Home" button in this menu, what should I do to add "Home" button to this menu ?

Comment: Show the code for your custom menu.

Comment: There's no code , I've just added the menu from the Menu tab in wordpress!

Comment: This is not a programming question then, try asking it here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Just insert "custom link" with adress to Your site.

Comment: One way to put this question is, how do you programmatically add a menu button with URL `get_bloginfo( 'url' );` to the beginning of the menu? This is the only way to make a true "home button" since "home" cannot be known when developing a theme. The menu is generated by wp_nav_menu so one would have to look for hooks there, use them to change the output and so on... this question would actually be appropriate here. But if you are not the theme author, if you only care about your site, you can (and should, really) add a custom link like Marcin says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try following with custom link and label as **HOME**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in Menu Page -> and add Custom Menu -> add Custom Links and Custom Name after save done..